# Unable to call aspx page web method using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Getting aspx page html when trying to call web method on aspx page.Here is the jQuery code

```
  $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Default.aspx/Hello',
            data: "{}",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('Success: ', response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is the web method code

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Hello()
    {
        string returnString = "hoiiiiiii";
        return returnString;
    }
```

Can any one point out what may be wrong.

Comment: Where is trigger for this ajax call ? Example like  $("#<%=txtFlceEmail.ClientID %>").autocomplete({

Comment: seems like u didn't noticed ..$(funtion()

Comment: ok i got it working i was missing contentType ...silly

Comment: Please add  dataType and contentType

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. You are missing the `contentType` in your jQuery `.ajax()` function.
2. You need to account for the `.d` value in the JSON response.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Default.aspx/Hello",
       data: "{}",
       async: false,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result) {
           if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
               // The .d is part of the result so reference it
               //  to get to the actual JSON data of interest
               console.log('Success: ', result.d);
           }
           else {
               // No .d; so just use result
               console.log('Success: ', result);
           }
       }
   });
   ```

---

> Note: The `.d` syntax was an anti-XSS protection put in by Microsoft in the ASP.NET 3.5 release of ASP.NET AJAX; therefore the check to see if the `.d` property is there or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could code like this: (This works for me very well)
I used jquery from CDN: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string myName
    {
        get { return "Hello"; }
    }
}
```

In your aspx.cs page:

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public static object MyMethod()
{
    return new MyClass();
}
```

And in your ASPX page:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "somepage.aspx/MyMethod",
            data: {},
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty("d"))
                    alert(data.d.myName);
                else
                    alert(data);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert(reponse);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Default.aspx/Hello',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Success: ', response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
    });
});
```

and the web method -

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string Hello()
{
    string returnString = "hoiiiiiii";
    return returnString;
}
```